# Inverse map measurable

Tags: real-analysis, integration, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure

We said that a function $f:X \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is measurable iff we have that for all $I_a:=(a,\infty)$, $a \in \mathbb{R}$ $f^{-1}(a,\infty)$ is measurable.

Now I want to show that $\frac{1}{f}$ is also measurable, if $f$ was measurable.

Therefore I look at exactly those open intervals.

(i)If $a>0$ we have that  $(\frac{1}{f})^{-1}(a,\infty) = f^{-1}(0,\frac{1}{a})$ which is measurable.

(ii)If $a = 0$ we have that $(\frac{1}{f})^{-1}(0,\infty) = f^{-1}(0,\infty)$ which is measurable.

(iii)But what happens for $a <0$ then we have that $(\frac{1}{f})^{-1}(a,\infty) =(\frac{1}{f})^{-1}(a,0] \cup (\frac{1}{f})^{-1}(0,\infty)$

The last one is known from the second case (ii), but what happens with the first one? I mean, you cannot have  0 as an actual result. $(\frac{1}{f})^{-1}(a,0)$ would be just $f^{-1}(-\infty,\frac{1}{a})$. But what does this 0 and are my calculations correct so far?

Comment: if $0\notin range\left(f\right)$ then $f^{-1}\left(\left\{0\right\}\right)=\emptyset$ (this helps you handling the semi closed interval)

Comment: okay and the rest was correct?

Comment: yes, looks quite correct. you showed that the property holds for a generator of that sigma algebra. should be fine.